# Alias Column Name

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a basic `select` Query in PostgreSQL, but I am having trouble using the column alias.  I tried to create the alias as `randomfield As [Space In Name]` but it gave an error of

> Error: syntax error at or near "["
>  Line 2: randomfield As [Space In Name]

And I also tried to do the alias w/o the brackets but that presented an error as well.  How do you alias with a space in `Postgresql`?

```
Select randomfield As [Space In Name]
From saledata
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#sql-syntax-identifiers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identifiers with special characters require [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#sql-syntax-identifiers) in SQL:

```
SELECT randomfield AS "Space in Name" FROM saledata
```